# Is adb backup usable in case of soft-brick?

Tags: adb, backup, nandroid

Let's assume I create a backup of my phone with this command:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

When I want to install Xposed framework it warns me that the phone maybe trap in re-booting or suffer from soft-brick so they advise the user to create a nondroid backup. my question is that is adb backup method helpful in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A softbrick usually renders the user unable to boot into Android OS successfully and satisfactorily, and most of the  time you can boot into a custom Recovery (you would be having it if you mentioned Xposed) and then use the ADB commands to restore the backup from there.

ADB backup method isn't useful in case of Xposed Framework since ADB doesn't make any image of `/system` or `/data` (Xposed makes changes into `/system`). ADB backup is concerned with user data (Apps, app data, settings, and similar things, internal/external SD card data) only. That's why Nandroid is recommended and always preferred.

Note that the command you mentioned will backup only shared storage (SD card), all apps (user+system) data and their apks as well. That's just it, but not enough to run a system.

Comment: In my case, (Android 4.2.1, 5.0) ADB backup isn't very stable. It intermittently stops backing up or resuming data without showing any warning. So I usually prefer Nandroid for imaging and TiBa for apps backup.

Comment: Ok. thanks a lot for your answer.
I have an sd card with limited free room. Is there anyway that I save the nondroid backup directly to pc and recover it from pc?

Comment: A user once posted this same query. I don't know how would you mount a PC folder or send Nandroid image on the fly. But I advised this: Take Nandroid backup in steps (1. `boot`, 2. `data`, 3. `system` ) and copy the backup (remember backup for only one step) using ADB or MTP into PC (you can do vice versa too). Your custom recovery may be showing the overall size of backup so you may make enough room for it in SD card step by step. // Honestly, you should ask it as a question so that other users can see it and may be suggest a good technique. :)

Comment: If you have OTG support and a spare USB drive/HDD then you're good to go.